# Does jQuery's .load() always automatically execute scripts?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I noticed if you `.load(url)` and the url is a page that contains scripts, those scripts are automatically executed. Is there a way to call `.load(url)` without the scripts executing, then perhaps execute them later? They seem to execute even if I've used `.load(url)` on an element that hasn't been appended to the document.

Answer (score 2):

jQuery's `load()` checks for `script` blocks and executes them (through its DOM manipulation helper code).

You could request the page with `$.ajax()` and then use the `html()` method to set the HTML - don't use `append()` as it will execute the `script` blocks too.

Answer (score 2):

I believe you can use `.get()`.
http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.get/

For example:

```
$.get('test.html', function(data) {
  // HTML text is now in data variable
  // If we use .html() the scripts are then executed.
  $('.result').html(data);
});
```

Also, from the `.load()` docs (http://api.jquery.com/load/):

> When calling .load() using a URL without a suffixed selector expression, the content is passed to .html() prior to scripts being removed. This executes the script blocks before they are discarded. If .load() is called with a selector expression appended to the URL, however, the scripts are stripped out prior to the DOM being updated, and thus are not executed.